# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect exception occur

Tags: java, networking, sockets

I have this code, can you help me to solve this problem?
I have written this code:

```
out = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());//exception occur

String content = (String) remoteUrlList.get(urlID + ".params");
content = (content == null ? "" : content + "&") + "content=" +   URLEncoder.encode(textArea.getText());
if (debug > 0) System.err.println("Capture: " + content);
out.writeBytes(content);
out.flush();
out.close();

// retrieve response from the remote host and display it.
if (debug > 0) System.err.println("Capture: reading response");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
String str;
while (null != ((str = in.readLine()))) {
  System.out.println("Capture: " + str);
}
in.close();

doneDialog.pack();
doneDialog.setVisible(true);
```

The error listing is:

```
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:157)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:233)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:795)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:743)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:654)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:832)
        at de.mud.jta.plugin.Capture.saveFile(Capture.java:339)
        at de.mud.jta.plugin.Capture.access$200(Capture.java:83)
        at de.mud.jta.plugin.Capture$4.actionPerformed(Capture.java:173)
        at de.mud.jta.plugin.Capture$10$1.actionPerformed(Capture.java:266)
```

I am trying this on my local network, so no issue of firewall..
Can anyone help?

krunal patel

Comment: You got to at least show the code snippet which you setup/configure the urlConnection object.

Comment: You show a stack trace, but not the actual exception that caused it. That could help.

Answer (score 1):

i got some thing some net, how to add proxy , when i tried this i am not getting Setting in project, configure so.. so please let me know how to do this.. see below for how to do this..

Configure it in the project Settings, tab Configurations, edit current Default profile, tab Server, add proxy settings to the 'Extra JVM parameters', for example add:

-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyserver.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80

Comment: Thank u all, i got solution,System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy name");
  System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "Port name");

Answer (score 0):

The address that you are connecting should exist. e.g. if you are opening a connection to localhost on port 8080, then there should be a server listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a firewall problem? check if you can reach the url through telnet by using: telnet url 80